# Output individual page header style and footer script using ACF

Tags: php, html, css, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to output custom CSS and footer script for individual pages in Wordpress using ACF. I am using a textarea field on ACF.

I have added this code to the header.php file.

```
if( get_field('custom_page_css')) {
$customCss = the_field('custom_page_css');
   echo '<style type="text/css" media="screen">' . $customCss . '</style>';
}
```

The issue is css outputs outside the style tag.

Comment: .acf-style { 
   display:none; 
}

<style type="text/css" media="screen"></style>

Answer (score 0):

Use the `get_field()` function:

```
$customCss = get_field('custom_page_css');
```

instead of

```
$customCss = the_field('custom_page_css');
```